# VS Code update issue

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, software-installation, updates, update-manager

I got this notification from the snap store

`pending update of code snap close the app to avoid disruption`

I have updated VS Code and But still this message did not disappear.

How do I fix this?

Comment: please add a log so that we can debug.

Comment: Quit the Code application. Try `sudo snap refresh code`. Carefully read the output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the notification bell icon continues to appear in the panel next to the clock even after the relevant snap package has been updated. If you ignore the notification icon or close the pending update notification by clicking the X, then the unnecessary notification icon will stop reappearing by itself in a few days after the Snap Store checks for updates.